# cruisecontrol show ant error message and it solve by itself

Tags: continuous-integration, build-automation, cruisecontrol

I'm seeing this error message recently,

> Ant Error Message: /opt/cruisecontrol/workdir/framework.xml:19: The following error occurred while executing this line: /opt/cruisecontrol/workdir/checkout/framework/source/framework.xml:103: The following error occurred while executing this line: /opt/cruisecontrol/workdir/checkout/framework/source/framework.xml:1101: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Before this the cruisecontrol is working fine without showing any error.
And then, after checking it again the cruisecontrol automatically fix the error by itself(not showing any error)

Can anyone enlighten me why is this happening to the cruisecontrol and why i am seeing that error?Is it a bug?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could happen if you have multiple build loops.
Use following command to find if there are multiple loops running.

```
ps aux | grep cruisecontrol
```